# C++ invalid conversion error using covariant return types with virtual functions

Tags: c++, c++11, virtual-functions, covariant-return-types

In the following code, I can assign the return of the `D::clone()` to a pointer to `B`, but not a pointer to `D`. Is is possible to return the actual polymorphic type from a call of the base pointer?

```
struct B
{
    virtual B * clone() { return this; }
};

struct D : B
{
    D * clone()
    {
        std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(this), D *>::value << std::endl;
        return this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    B * b = new D();
    B * bb = b->clone(); // prints "1"
    std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(b->clone()), D *>::value << std::endl; // prints "0"
    D * d = b->clone(); // error: invalid conversion from B * to D * (GCC 5.1)
}
```

Comment: Compiler is right - by `b->clone()` you call this function `B* B::clone()` but in polymorphic way. Compiler would see the covariant type if `b`was of `D*`type - not `B*` type...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  A call of `clone()` on the base `B` class of a `D` will return the `D*` cast to a `B*`.

You can reverse this by doing a `static_cast<D*>` if you are absolutely certain, or a `dynamic_cast<D*>` if you are not certain.  If you are certain, than you should really make the variable `b` be a `D*`.

In C++, you should encode what you know about the state of the program at compile time regardless of the run time situation as types.  By storing the `D*` into `B* b`, you are telling the compiler **not** to "know" that the data being pointed to "is a `D`".  Instead, you are saying "the code using `B*b` should be valid for any pointer-to-`B`.  Clearly `D* d = b->clone();` is not guaranteed to be valid for every pointer-to-`B`.

Comment: Right, what I'm really trying to do is determine the dynamic type of an object from a pointer to base. And I can't use dynamic_cast type switch because the derived objects are template classes with unknown type arguments. I was hoping to avoid the visitor pattern but it appears that there is not a way around it.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod is there some fixed operation you want to do on the derived objects?  What about the type arguments do you need to know?  Are you trying to pull off double-dispatch, where the operation's details depend on two discrete code bases?  Try asking about your particular problem, with an attempted solution, and why you don't like it.  Simply asking how to solve a sub-problem (without the larger context) can often restrict the ability of people to find solutions.

Comment: No there is no fixed operation, but the operation does depend on the dynamic type, so that is the problem. I actually have a complete solution using visitor pattern but I wanted to know the answer to this sub problem independently.